# Pass the Firebase's Download URL using click using Ion-Item-Option

Tags: html, angular, firebase, ionic-framework

According to Ionic documentation, `ion-item-option` have a `href` attribute that sets hyperlinks or links.

Link of Documentation: https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/item-option

I used this type of method to list the Firebase Download URL of my files and when the user clicks `ion-item-option`, the file explorer will open and downloading of file will be possible but unfortunately the button (ion-item-option) is unresponsive. Is there any way to do it?

```
  <ion-list>
    <ion-item-sliding *ngFor="let file of files | async">
      <ion-item detail>
        <ion-icon name="document-attach-outline" slot="start"></ion-icon>
        <ion-label>
          <h2>{{ file.title }}</h2>
        </ion-label>
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item-options>
        <!-- This is the href attribute -->
        <ion-item-option color="success" [href]="file.downloadUrl">
          <ion-icon name="cloud-download" slot="icon-only"></ion-icon>
        </ion-item-option>
        <ion-item-option color="danger">
          <ion-icon name="trash-bin" slot="icon-only"></ion-icon>
        </ion-item-option>
      </ion-item-options>
    </ion-item-sliding>
  </ion-list>
```

Comment: Do you get any kind of errors in the console?

Comment: @Callan actually no errors. Just no results